# Is it possible to add a function to refresh the page for this code?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop

I want to add refresh page function to "Add to basket" in my prestashop. It is possible (code from ajax-card.js file)?

```
    overrideButtonsInThePage : function(){
      //for every 'add' buttons...
      $('.ajax_add_to_cart_button').unbind('click').click(function(){
         var idProduct =  $(this).attr('rel').replace('nofollow', '').replace('ajax_id_product_', '');
         if ($(this).attr('disabled') != 'disabled')
            ajaxCart.add(idProduct, null, false, this);
         return false;
      });
      //for product page 'add' button...
      $('#add_to_cart input').unbind('click').click(function(){
         ajaxCart.add( $('#product_page_product_id').val(), $('#idCombination').val(), true, null, $('#quantity_wanted').val(), null);
         return false;
      });
```

Comment: `window.location.reload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.refresh-button').click(Function(){
     location.reload();
})
```